# Shell script to loop over the list of strings

Tags: shell, sh

Below is my variable declaration and in the shell script, I am looking for a way to loop over the list of strings to get each item.

```
output='['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt', 'd.txt']'
```

I tried the script below but it is not working as expected

```
for i in "${output}"; do
    echo $i
   
done
```

Expected result:

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
d.txt
```

Comment: You set your variable to the string `[a.txt, b.txt, c.txt, d.txt]`. First, if you put square brackets into the string, you can't expect the pieces coming out without square bracket, so at best you can expect in the output `[a.txt`, ...., `d.txt]`. But this works only if you split the string at the spaces. By using double quotes (`"${output}"`), you basically ask the shell explicitly to **not** split the string. Therefore, your loop body is executed only once, with `i` bound to the complete string.

Answer (score 6):

In your attempt, quoting the variable forced the shell to regard it as a single value. Failing to quote when you need to is a common beginner error, but quoting when you *want* the shell to split a value on whitespace (and expand wildcards in the result) is also wrong. Perhaps see also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

As long as your items are just tokens, you can save them in a string.

```
output='a.txt b.txt c.txt d.txt'
for item in $output; do
   echo "$item"  # remember quotes here
done
```

In isolation, the variable doesn't buy you anything, though.

```
for item in a.txt b.txt c.txt d.txt
do
    ...
```

or, if all you want is to print the tokens one by one, simply

```
printf '%s\n' a.txt b.txt c.txt d.txt
```

The only data type in `sh` is a string. There is no simple and safe way to store a sequence of items which require quoting in a variable. (If you can completely control the input, and know what you are doing, try `eval`; but often, one or both of these conditions are not true.)

As suggested above, if you can avoid saving the values in a variable, you can use any quoting you like!

```
for item in "an item" another \
    'yet one more (with "nested quotes" even, see?)'
do
    echo "$item"  # now the quotes are important!
done
```

Bash and Ksh etc have arrays, so you can do things like

```
items=("an item" another 'yet one more (with "nested quotes" even, see?)')
printf '%s\n' "${items[@]}"
```

but this is not available in plain `sh`.

(For what it's worth, you also cannot nest quotes the way you tried to.

```
input='['a.txt', '
```

creates a string consisting of (quoted) `[` immediately adjacent to (unquoted) `a.txt` imrediately adjacent to (quoted) comma and space. The shell will simply join together the adjacent strings into a single string after quote removal.)

Comment: Regarding the quote in the two `echo "$item"` lines, is there another reason for their presence beside preventing wildcard expansion ?

Comment: Quotes prevent whitespace tokenization and wildcard expansion. For `echo` in particular, whitespace tokenization is not important, but the general rule should be to always quote _uniess_ you want to force whitespace tokenization and wildcard expansion. See also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists:%7E:text=A%20list%20is%20a%20sequence%20of%20one%20or%20more%20pipelines%20separated%20by%20one%20of%20the%20operators%20%E2%80%98%3B%E2%80%99%2C%20%E2%80%98%26%E2%80%99%2C%20%E2%80%98%26%26%E2%80%99%2C%20or%20%E2%80%98%7C%7C%E2%80%99%2C%20and%20optionally%20terminated%20by%20one%20of%20%E2%80%98%3B%E2%80%99%2C%20%E2%80%98%26%E2%80%99%2C%20or%20a%20newline.) of GNU Bash,

> "A list is a sequence of one or more pipelines separated by one of the
> operators ‘;’, ‘&’, ‘&&’, or ‘||’, and optionally terminated by one of
> ‘;’, ‘&’, or a newline."

Also, you need to remember Bash supports one-dimensional numerically indexed and associative array types, unfortunately, as per my knowledge bash doesn't support a "List" type data structure.

And for that reason you need to modify your variable declaration like the below:

```
output=("a.txt" "b.txt" "c.txt" "d.txt")
```

Comment: There is no indication that the OP asks about a Bash solution; the question is conspicuously only tagged [tag:sh]. If they were to adopt your solution, they would also have to use array syntax to loop over the values.